# Asphalt patching

Tags: repair, railing, patch, asphalt

I want to build a fence on one edge of a parking place beside my house, which is paved with asphalt. The parking place is sloped and uneven on its edge where the fence is to be installed. I'm thinking of pouring asphalt along the edge of the parking place over existing asphalt to make the sloped edge flat and the uneven spots smooth so that a railing for the fence's gate can be installed on the top of the patched edge. Is such asphalt patch strong enough for the railing?

Comment: it almost sounds like you want to bolt a railing post to asphalt. lol

Comment: Probably not.  You’ll want to install fence posts thru the asphalt and deep in the ground.  After the fence is in place THEN patch the asphalt.

Comment: Deep and packed dirt, or concrete for your posts, then install the fence and after this, patch any asphalt that "needs" patching. Asphalt is tar and rock, not a strong suitable substrate for attaching anything to. It would work, but for how long....how much load are we talking....weather....asphalt flexes and crumbles.

Comment: @Tyson that goes in the answer section below :)